# iOS appstore distribution certificate is not found even though it's in keychain

Tags: ios, xcode, ad-hoc-distribution, macos-catalina, app-store-connect

My Distribution certificate is installed in my mac.
When I try to upload the app it says no distribution certificate is found.

I don't understand why

FYI:
I recently upgraded to catalina.
Do I have to explicitly add some permission or something ?

Before catalina I was able to upload my app to itunes connect.

Comment: Does Xcode agree that you have the certificate? The Accounts pref pane will tell you.

Comment: Xcode doesn't agree. It says no certificate found when I try to upload the build.

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue.  Could be some kind of apple issue.

Just tried uploading the app via *xcode 10.3* then after that whenever I tried uploading via *xcode 11.1* or *11.3* I never experienced the problem again.

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the distribution certificate again from developer console and add it in the keychain .

Comment: distribution certificate is in portal but private key won't be available right ?

Comment: Then get that private key and add it in your keyckain. If you cannot find the required private key , only option left is to create a new private key using your system